# How to hide body with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to hide all content and show some text like 'Test Over' in my webpage after a particular date. I have created a function but it doesn't work properly. Please help me to sort this issue.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myDate=new Date();
    myDate.setFullYear(2015,2,14);
    var today = new Date();
    if (myDate>today)
    {
        document.body.style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It'd help if you post the code you tried and didn't work as expected.

Comment: What function you created?

Comment: yea well how about waiting till its actually the 14th to see if your function works?

Comment: the best idea is fix a common class for all your elements and hide it , it is very simple

Comment: vjdhama, i have posted the code.

Comment: All user-visible content in the DOM is in the `<body>`/`document.body`; if you don't show the `<body>` where exactly did you expect your 'test over' element to be shown?

Comment: I need to remove all content on body tag and show my defined text in function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach I could think of:

```
var myDate = new Date(),
    today = new Date(),
    // create an element to contain your content:
    note = document.createElement('h1');
// set the content of that created-element:
note.textContent = 'Test Over';

// remember that, in JavaScript, months are zero-indexed,
// 0 = January, 1 = February (you were originally testing
// against a date in March):
myDate.setFullYear(2015, 1, 14);

if (myDate > today) {
  // while there's any content in the <body>:
  while (document.body.firstChild){
    // we remove that content, each time removing the
    // firstChild:
    document.body.removeChild(document.body.firstChild);
  }
  // appending the created-element:
  document.body.appendChild(note);
}
```

```js
var myDate = new Date(),
    today = new Date(),
    note = document.createElement('h1');
note.textContent = 'Test Over';

myDate.setFullYear(2015, 1, 14);

if (myDate > today) {
  while (document.body.firstChild){
    document.body.removeChild(document.body.firstChild);
  }
  document.body.appendChild(note);
}
```

```html
<h1>This text should not be visible</h1>
```

References:

- [`Date()` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).
- [`Date.prototype.setFullYear()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setFullYear).
- [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement).
- [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild).
- [`Node.firstChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.firstChild).
- [`while()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while).

Comment: When i run your code here, it is working fine but when i use this code in my page then it is not working. What could be reason for this?

Comment: That you've put your `<script>` tags in the head of the page, and not as the last element before the closing `</body>` tag, probably.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Code is working fine when i put script before the closing </body> tag. Is there any way to use script in head tag?

Comment: Yes, and if you search this site - or the internet in general - you'll probably find lots of ways to do so.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to hide the body **After** the designated date, then you need to check if your date is **smaller** than today meaning if it passed, not the other way around

```js
var myDate = new Date();
myDate.setFullYear(2015, 1, 11);
var today = new Date();
if (myDate < today) {
  // this will just replace the body's html with your text
  document.body.innerHTML="some text";
}
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.beforeDate {
  background: red;
}
.afterDate {
  background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<div class="afterDate">This one will be hidden after the date</div>
```

**UPDATE:**

if you want to put your script in the head, you need to make sure it doesnt run before the elements in the body are created, so you wont try to alter objects that do not exist yet.

you can do it by attaching a custom handler to the document's load event, which will fire when the DOM is loaded and there you put your script:

```
document.addEventListener("load", function () {
    var myDate = new Date();
    myDate.setFullYear(2015, 1, 11);
    var today = new Date();
    if (myDate < today) {
        // this will just replace the body's html with your text
        document.body.innerHTML = "some text";
    }
},true);
```

Comment: @SureshKumar can you be more specific? not working how?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Code is working fine when i put script before the closing </body> tag. Is there any way to use script in head tag?